# Is there any recommend code generation mean that is suitable to substitute C macro?

Tags: c, clang, code-generation, c-preprocessor

I just started working on a large legacy code base. It has a lot of variables and structures that are named in a plain text "definition file". Then some header files will include these definition files and use **C** preprocessor to generate the variable declaration and getter/setter.

This cause huge pain in working and modifying the fields. Also, the signatures of getter/setter are not generated until compile time, so there is no intellisense support for them, too.

I am thinking of generate the code before compile time and ask other modules to include the generated header files rather than include the preprocessor based header. I looked into Python + clang and adding keyword into **C** language. But both of them are overwhelming and I don't know how to start with. So I would like to ask about the way people would recommend to address the problem.

edit:
The code base is not belong to me, so I cannot copy and paste.
But I can mimic the the code and it would look like:

```
// in the definition file
NEWVARIABLE( point, int )

// in the preprocessor header file
#define NEWVARIABLE( name, type ) \
static type name;\
type LIBNAME_Get##name##(){return name ; }\
void LIBNAME_Set##name##( type _##name ){ name = _##name ; }
```

Sometimes these preprocessor generated functions or data will interleave with function pointers and make it even more crazy.

Comment: The code uses the C preprocessor, to pre-process a file which is NOT valid C code, to generate actual declarations?  Obviously the original designer thought this was a big advantage.   Are you missing something? (e.g., just modifying the not-C file to make field changes?)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can just run the precompiler (`gcc -E` for example with the GCC compiler) and then cut and save the resulting text. Not very nice, but it will be difficult to get it better automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GCC then `gcc -save-temps Code.c` .It will generate a preprocessed file as Code.i and all the macros will be substituted here. (Not Sure what you want)

Answer (score 0):

There is no obvious need to generate function names at compile time. Only the functions actually called from the program will get linked into the executable. So you should perhaps ask yourself whether those macros fill any purpose, then consider replacing them with all possible combinations of functions. (Perhaps inline functions if the program is performance-critical.)

But then, it is often a bad idea to make too drastic changes to existing programs, depending on the size and complexity of the program.

For any more detailed answer than this, you will have to post some code.

Answer (score 0):

If your scope of interest includes commercial solutions, I can recommend you to check out our web site http://www.cdsan.com. We provide custom refactoring and converters. It looks that it would be possilbe to convert your files with reasonable effort.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to replace a standard C idiom (by the way, I wouldn't be surprised if you find the definition file included elsewhere with other definitions of the macro) by something else which would add dependencies in your build process which aren't present yet.

I wouldn't do it. That isn't broken or bad, it is just you who is unfamiliar with the technique.

If my experience of large legacy code is applicable, you should have a lot of opportunities to improve things which are unarguably broken; work on those.